# GetAllInstance with asp.net 5 built in dependency inection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to have service locator pattern in ASP.NET5 (MVC6) Application. So what I want to do is get all instance of my interfaces.

I don't want to use any other DI Frameworks as I know this is already available in DI Containers like structuremap and autofac.

I want to do something like get all instances of ITask interface. Following is a interface code.

```
public Interface ITask
{
    void Execute();
}

//What I want to do
foreach (var task in container.GetAllInstances<ITask>())
{
    task.Execute();
}
```

Here what I want to do. I want to get all instance of ITask. Then I want to get all instances of ITask and execute call execute method of that class.

Any help will be appreciated!. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that some instances have been added to the DI you should be able to do something like this:

```
var allInstance = container.GetService<IEnumerable<ITest>>();
```

Comment: can you please provide some more code and details. Also I am not able to find container with default dependency injection

Comment: you just take a dependency on IServiceProvider and it can be injected

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do please paste your code there.

Comment: I think you should show more of your code for me to understand where you are needing the service container